# Proof of $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\int\limits_{x/2}^{x}\frac{\cos \frac{1}{t}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to prove that
$$
\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\int\limits_{x/2}^{x}\frac{\cos \frac{1}{t}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t=0 \;,
$$ but I have no idea how to prove it. I have tried substitution by letting $y=\frac{1}{t}$, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I have tried to make a bound of $\cos \frac{1}{t}$, but as $t\to0^+$, $\cos \frac{1}{t}$ oscillates, so that it is of no use. How can I prove it?

Thank you.

Comment: L'Hospital should help here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The substitution $s=1/t$ and $y=1/x$ is fine. We have that
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\int\limits_{x/2}^{x}\frac{\cos \frac{1}{t}}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t=\lim\limits_{y\to +\infty}\int\limits_{y}^{2y}\frac{\cos s}{s} \,\mathrm{d}s\\
=\lim\limits_{y\to +\infty}\int\limits_{1}^{2y}\frac{\cos s}{s} \,\mathrm{d}s-\lim\limits_{y\to +\infty}\int\limits_{1}^{y}\frac{\cos s}{s} \,\mathrm{d}s=L-L=0$$
where
$$L=\int\limits_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos s}{s} ds=\left[\frac{\sin s}s\right]_{1}^{+\infty}+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin s}{s^2}ds<+\infty$$
because
$$\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin s|}{s^2}ds\leq \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s^2}ds=1$$
and [absolute convergence implies convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Absolute_convergence_of_integrals).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as far as I have tried, I can't get how $L$ converges. All I can get is $-1-\sin1 < L < 1-\sin1$, which could possibly indicates that L oscillates between those two endpoints.

Comment: Note that if an integral is absoluteley convergent then it is convergent

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence#Absolute_convergence_of_integrals